# Email: Send is OK, but Job status is Error

Tags: marketing-cloud

When I create new "Send" object by SOAP API I receives a response "StatusCode: OK", but I don't have this email in my mailbox.

When I checking status of "Send" object in "Status" attribute is value "Error" and any more information about it.

How I can get full error message to check what is wrong in email template or sent attributes?

Comment: Make sure not to leave your question open - if it's solved, select the checkbox as answered. If it is unresolved, let me know how else I can help.

Comment: Did your question get answered?

Answer (score 1):

Once the send has started, and a JobID has been created, there isn't a way through the API to determine why it has failed, only that it has failed.  You would want to run the Validate function through the UI on your email to see what errors may be happening.

[Here is more on Validate.](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/validate/)